# Align number values by decimal material ui table react

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

In my React application I'm using Material UI table to display the list of products. I would like to align the price by decimal point.
[image: table]

Comment: If you can add 0 in decimal point then you can add toFixed() after the number like price.toFixed(4)

Comment: @Arpit thank you for your suggestion, but I don't want to add zero's if there are no decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function like this code and you can pass `number` in `numberFormat`. You can change `maxSpace` value and `paddingRight` multiply value whatever you need. Check this working example code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-dcxcf?file=/demo.js:890-1128)

```
const numberFormat = num => {
  let len = 0;
  if (num.toString().split(".")[1] >= 0) {
    len = num.toString().split(".")[1].length;
  }
  const maxSpace = 4;
  return <div style={{ paddingRight: (maxSpace - len) * 8 }}>{num}</div>;
};
```

Check this image, you can change paddingRight for every row as your need

[image]

Comment: Arpit thank you for your answer. I did something similar but had problems with '.' alignment. You can clearly see in the above pic you have attached '.' is not aligned. Its because the numbers widths are different. I tried adding this css which would give same width https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings but for some reason it is not working.

Comment: You can change `paddingRight` value, I changed `multiply` value to 8 and it's working fine now. You can see in image. When You will add this code, you should update `paddingRight` multiply value